# How to test a hypothesis about two categorical data sets?

Tags: categorical-data

assuming we have two data sets of e-mails. All e-mails were sent to people and contain a link which was clicked. Furthermore, we know how fast the link was clicked.

The first column in the following data sets describes how fast the link was clicked, i.e., 1.0 means within the first minute, 2.0 within the second minute, and the second column describes in how many e-mails the link was clicked within this time, i.e., in 1013 e-mails, the link was clicked in the first minute.

Data set A:

```
1.0    1013
2.0     114
3.0      40
4.0      22
5.0      17
```

Data set B:

```
1.0    780
2.0    150
3.0     37
4.0     22
5.0     15
```

The number of e-mails in both data sets is different. Nevertheless, it seems like links are clicked a little later in the second data set than in the first data set. But is there a statistical test I could use to test this hypothesis? All characteristics which might affect whether a link is clicked faster or slower are not relevant, i.e., please ignore whether the e-mails/links are the same etc. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can test hypothesis, but you can't **prove** anything about the populations.. // If you want to view times as nominal categories, you could use a chi-squared test of independence in a 2×2 table with row categories A and B, and column categories 'Fast (< 1 min)' and 'Slow (> 1min)'. That seems to throw away a lot of information and I wouldn't do it, but the P-value of the test turns out to be very nearly 0.// [Scholarly paper](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/articles/agresti_1981.pdf) includes ordinal by nominal tables.

Answer (score 1):

a simple two-sample t-test for the mean click time should be sufficient for your purpose (see here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Uses

but take care that your sample size is large enough in order for your means to follow approximately normal distributions).

If you want to compare the two full distributions of clicking times however, then you may consider a chi-square test

Comment: With only one sample mean from each group, it seems to be hard to be sure sample size is large enough for means to be normal. As I say, I wouldn't use 2-sample t because of extreme skewness, but that's a matter of opinion. Anyhow, interesting answer (+1).

Comment: What's the problem? Using t-tests is ok, as long as the conditions of the Central Limit Theorem are satisfied (i.e. large sample size, independence and finite variance). I would feel bad about it if the data were from e.g. a heavy-tailed distribution, but here we are dealing with a small number of numerical categories from a large number of independent sources, so I see problem in using a t-test.

Comment: The issue is how large a sample makes up for how much skewness. Not _obvious_ to me that 1000 is large enough here. 10,000 maybe. I said it's a matter of opinion. You have a right to yours, of course.

Comment: I agree, skewness plays a role for CLTs convergence properties and thus for the sample size. Thus, to take care of this, one should first have a look at the bootstrapped distribution of the mean, which I thought you have already done in your comment below

Answer (score 1):

The data can be put into a more usual (sorted) format as follows:

```
a = rep(1:5, c(1013,114,40,22,17))
b = rep(1:5, c( 756,150,37,22,15))
```

Summary statistics for the two datasets are as follows:

```
summary(a);  sd(a);  length(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.272   1.000   5.000 
[1] 0.7371543  # sample SD
[1] 1206       # sample size

summary(b);  sd(b);  length(b)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   1.000   1.000   1.357   1.000   5.000 
[1] 0.7900039  # sample SD
[1] 980        $ sample size
```

The mean click time is lower for Group A (1.272) 
than for Group B (1.357), as you say.
Histograms give a visual impression that the two samples seem different.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 hist(a, br=(0:5)+.5, ylim=c(0,1300),lab=T, col="skyblue2")
 hist(b, br=(0:5)+.5, ylim=c(0,1300),lab=T, col="skyblue2")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

The data in both groups are so strongly right-skewed
that I would not feel comfortable using a two-sample
t test. Even though sample sizes are very large,
I question whether the legendary robustness of
t tests ought to be pushed to the point of using
them for data as strongly skewed as yours. (I realize
this is a matter of opinion, with further comment
in the end note.)

Although the sample medians are equal, it seems
clear that the sample for A is 'located' below the
sample for B. When data are highly discrete and the sample median
is the minimum value (as here), the sample median can be
deceptive as a measure of location: 16% of A values exceed $1$ and 23% of B values exceed $1.$

```
mean(a > median(a))
[1] 0.1600332
mean(b > median(b))
[1] 0.2285714
```

A two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test, shows that
the difference in location is highly significant (P-value $0.0001).$

```
wilcox.test(a,b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test 
      with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 552150, p-value = 0.0001122
alternative hypothesis: 
   true location shift is not equal to 0
```

*Note:* A permutation test on these data using the t statistic
as metric, is done as follows. We permute the 2186 values in both of the samples at random into two groups of 1286 and 980 respectively, and find the t statistic 
that compares the two groups. By doing this many times
we can simulate the permutation distribution of the t statistic.

The P-value of the permutation test is
the proportion of the many permuted t values with
absolute values greater than the absolute value of
the t statistic for the original (undisturbed) groups.

This method takes for granted that the t statistic is
an effective way to compare two groups, but it does not
assume that the t statistic has Student's t distribution.
We use the Welch form of the t statistic.

The P-value of the permutation test is $0.0087,$ significant at the 1% level. There were $9711$ distinct
values `t.prm`--enough make a useful permutation distribution. The Welch t test on the original data
gives P-value $0.0099.$

That the two P-values are
nearly the same might be given as an argument that
it is OK to use a t test on the original data.

```
x = c(a,b); g = rep(1:2, c(1206,980))
t.obs = t.test(x ~ g)$stat
set.seed(1234)
t.prm = replicate(10^4, 
        t.test(x ~ sample(g, 2186, rep=T))$stat)
mean(abs(t.prm) > abs(t.obs))
[1] 0.0087             # P-value
length(unique(t.prm))
[1] 9711
```

Comment: What's the problem? Using t-tests is ok, as long as the conditions of the Central Limit Theorem are satisfied (i.e. large sample size, independence and finite variance). I would feel bad about it if the data were from e.g. a heavy-tailed distribution, but here we are dealing with a small number of numerical categories from a large number of independent sources, so I see no problem in using a t-test.

Comment: Since you have already put big effort into your code, it would be interesting to see how the means are distributed, when bootstrapping subsamples from the data. From this one can then infer, if the conditions imposed on the t-test are satisfied or not

Comment: I bootstrapped sample A for averages of 1206 and got a dist'n that looked fairly close to normal.`a.avg = replicate(10^5, mean(sample(a, 1206, rep=T)));` `hist(a.avg)`